# Removing custom post type name in single article URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

My articles are not standard posts but custom post types (not sure about how to formulate this exactly). When viewing an article in single view, the URL is : my_site.com/custom_type_name/article_title, whereas I want: my_site.com/article_title, just like with normal posts.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `post_type_link` hook, like this for use hash in link

`faq` is the example custom post type

```
add_action( 'post_type_link', 'wpse70763_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse70763_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

    $post_type = 'faq';

    if ( $post->post_type === $post_type )
        $link = get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) . '#' . $post->post_name;

    return $link;
}
```

then `unset($wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['faq'])`

On the init of your CPT unset the pemastructure

- see [the answer 12762](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/custom-post-type-no-need-for-single-view-plus-want-permalink-rewrites-that-inc) for help and more information

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a hash..

Comment: Yes, this is only a example. You must use the source. This is not the ready solution.